# Create XML Schema with same element but different attribute name

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I'm trying to create a xsd from a xml file. The xml contains a FLD element, but the name attribute specifies the name of the field, I'm trying to create the xsd so that it creates all the field element names in the xsd, Ive used the XML Schema Definition Tool (xsd.exe), but it only creates one FLD element. Below is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PARAM>
  <GRP ID="GRP1">
    <FLD NAME="LSTOFCY" TYPE="Char"/>
    <FLD NAME="LITMREF" TYPE="Char"/>
    <FLD NAME="LLOT" TYPE="Char"/>
    <FLD NAME="LLOCSRC" TYPE="Char"/>
    <FLD NAME="LLOCDES" TYPE="Char"/>
    <FLD NAME="LSERNUM" TYPE="Char"/>
    <FLD NAME="LSOHNUM" TYPE="Char"/>
    <FLD NAME="LSOPLIN" TYPE="Integer"/>
    <FLD NAME="LQTY" TYPE="Decimal"/>
    <FLD NAME="LSTAT" TYPE="Integer"/>
    <FLD NAME="LMES" TYPE="Char"/>
  </GRP>
</PARAM>
```

Is there another tool that will be able to create the schema with all the fields?

Comment: So, you want to create a schema, from a schema?

Comment: No, above is the xml, I want to create the schema from the xml.

Comment: I was being facetious. What you have there is an xml document, but it's an xml document that's already describing a schema. xsd.exe can't possibly figure that out so you'd need to write something manually either in code, or using xslt-transformation to output a file, or some other option.

Comment: Thanks J. I thought I had to do that, I will then manually create the schema in code, and just create the elements by reading the Name attribute, and writing my xsd elements. The above xml is what I got back from the SAGE X3 web service. I will play around with the code.

Comment: Good luck. xsd.exe does have its limitations. =)

Comment: Thanks. So I've noticed, I thought I will get this app done quickly, but now that xsd.exe didn't work as I was hoping for, I will write code to create the schema. =)